# Winston createLogger custom function

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

In my node application I use winston for error logging. I want to create a function at one place and use it in server.js file. This is my file

```
const exceptionLogger = () => {
  createLogger({
    exceptionHandlers: [
      new transports.File({ filename: 'exceptions.log' }),
    ],
  });
};
```

But this function can't be called as ***exceptionLogger()***.
It crashes the app. What is the reason for this? How can I do this in a correct way??

Comment: did you export the function?

Comment: Yes I exported it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
export const exceptionLogger = () => {
  winston.createLogger({
    exceptionHandlers: [
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'exceptions.log' }),
    ],
  });
};
```

Comment: I exported this Dino